# Init variable using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to init a variable using AngularJS in my template... It seems not working.

Template :

```
<div class="eventList" ng-controller="EventOfCategoryController">
  <input type="hidden" ng-init="categoryId = <%=id%>" />
</div>
```

Js :

```
app.controller("EventOfCategoryController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  console.log($scope.categoryId); //undefined
  $http.get('/category/'+$scope.categoryId).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // my functions
  });
});
```

Comment: Better to put the initialization code inside the controller.

Comment: I encountered the same issue and noticed, angular takes some time to init values. ie, you are accessing that value, before it is set.  For testing, you might set a timeout and check you get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read the set value before Angular is done assigning.

```
app.controller("EventOfCategoryController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $timeout(function(){
        console.log($scope.categoryId);
    },1000);
  $http.get('/category/'+$scope.categoryId).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // my functions
  });
});
```

Ideally you should use $watch as bellow if you need to use ng-init at all:

```
app.controller("EventOfCategoryController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
    console.log('test');
    $scope.$watch("categoryId", function(){
        console.log($scope.categoryId);
$http.get('/category/'+$scope.categoryId).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // my functions
  });
    });
});
```

You can also use a method in you ng-init as follows. This will reduce watch load and increase performance.

```
app.controller("EventOfCategoryController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
        console.log('test');
        $scope.init = function(categoryId){
            console.log(categoryId);
    $http.get('/category/'+categoryId).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // my functions
      });
        });
    });
```

And ng-int as

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="init(<%=id%>)" />
```

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I tryed to use your code for my problem too but its not working. Could you help me out with my problem too? :)

40919155

Answer (score 0):

you shoud init the variable in your controller:

```
app.controller("EventOfCategoryController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.categoryId = 7;  
  console.log($scope.categoryId); //undefined
  $http.get('/category/'+$scope.categoryId).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // my functions
  });
});
```

And

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="categoryId">
```

Comment: I can not doing that because `id` is send from the server :/ See edit in the template..

Answer (score 0):

The controller(EventOfCategoryController) is being created before the categoryId variable is added to the $scope object.

```
$scope.$watch('categoryId', function () {
    console.log($scope.categoryId); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap `console.log` in a `setTimeout` and utilise a `$scope.$apply`, `categoryId` will become available:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            console.log($scope.categoryId); // 7
        });
    }, 0);
```